# Silent hard drive upgrade for late 2008 macbook

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, upgrade, macbook

I want to upgrade my macbook hard drive to a bigger one. I have a Samsung HM320JI with 320 GB but it's too noisy. The original hitachi is much more silent.

Can you recommend a silent hard drive to upgrade a late 2008 macbook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't looking for more storage, I'd recommend a Solid State Disk. With zero noise emission, far better performance compared to conventional 'platter' hard drives and, as a bonus, a more 'robust' Macbook.